# Ember-Cli-Mirage 404

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

Just followed the [documentation](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/quickstart/) but every time I navigate or call to the url, it returns 404 for me

```
// app/mirage/config.js
export default function() {

  this.get('/api/users', function() {
    return {
      users: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Zelda'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Link'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Epona'},
      ]
    }
  });

}
```

*Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError: /api/users*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Upon rereading your question: are you navigating from within your app or going straight to the URL or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigating directly to that URL in your browser will not follow the mirage pipeline. Rather, when your ember application would have queried the end points you have configured, mirage will send mocked data instead. Therefore you need to implement something that will call your endpoint from **within** your Ember app.

Comment: Okay, the key is to manually restart the ember serveri after you change the file, sad face..

Comment: Even I missed restarting `ember serve`. /facepalm. Thanks @LYu